# Field as a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with similar data, I am looking for a way to combine the [city] and [street] fields into one field.
The [street] field was a substring for the [city] field and find the sum across the [city] field
Expected result below:

```
city/street   value1    value2  value3  total
Wien            16        50      6       72
Quadenstrabe    14        46      1       61
Laberlsteg      2         4       5       11
Hamburg         7         9       5       21
Esplanade       3         7       4       14
Drehbahn        4         2       1       7
```

How to do it in mssql?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE](
[city] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[street] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[value1] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[value2] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[value3] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[total] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


insert into [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE] values('Wien','Quadenstrabe','14','46','1','61')
insert into [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE] values('Wien','Laberlsteg','2','4','5','11')
insert into [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE] values('Hamburg','Esplanade','3','7','4','14')
insert into [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE] values('Hamburg','Drehbahn','4','2','1','7')

select * from [dbo].[#CITY_TABLE]
```

Comment: do you have any additional column for making the relation between city and street?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as an `nvarchar`...?

Comment: How to do what exactly?   What's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: Seems the OP has vacated the topic with no response on the datatype issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided you fix your datatype and don't use an `nvarchar` to store an `int`, this works:

```
SELECT ISNULL(street, city) AS CityStreet,
       SUM([Value1]) AS Value1,
       SUM([Value2]) AS Value2,
       SUM([Value3]) AS Value3,
       SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM #CITY_TABLE
GROUP BY city, street WITH ROLLUP
HAVING city IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CityStreet DESC;
```

Comment: `Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator` :) . Cast it to `INT`

Comment: @Sami the answer suggests fixing the data type first.

Comment: To quote the only non-SQL in my answer (but emphasis added): *"Provided you **fix your datatype** and don't use an `nvarchar` to store an `int`, this works:"*

Comment: I guess you could also convert the `nvarchar` to `int`  but fixing the datatype seems really necessary here

Comment: @GuidoG agreed, storing numerical values in an `(n)varchar` is rarely a good idea, especially as it's clear the OP is aggregating the values at city level. Without a good reason, I'm not entertaining casting the values in the `SELECT` and the "correct" answer is fixing the data.

Comment: @Larnu I know, but I mean in case the OP can't change the datatype for some reasons :)

Comment: @Sami then the OP better have a good reason; they are yet to reply on the subject as yet.

Comment: To confirm, (as my answer was editted), I am not entertaining the casting of the value in the `SELECT`; at least not without the OP giving good reason as to why the datatype can't be changed. Storing numerical values as an`(n)varchar` almost always causes more problems than it solves; and casting all the values instead of fixing the data doesn't address that issue.

Comment: I am also curious for such a reason. If the reason is that sometimes other chars can be in that column, than he can forget about summing all togheter. It just makes no sense to me

Comment: Exactly, if they are storing non-numerical values, then there is a much larger problem at hand, if their aim is to aggregate those non-numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

Your life would be much easier if Value1, Value2, Value3, and Total were datatype int. But, with what you have:

```
SELECT 
    CITY [City/Street],
    SUM(convert(int,VALUE1)) [Value1],
    SUM(convert(int,VALUE2)) [Value2],
    SUM(convert(int,VALUE3)) [Value3],
    SUM(convert(int,TOTAL)) [Value1] from 
[dbo].#CITY_TABLE GROUP BY CITY
UNION
SELECT 
    STREET, 
    convert(int,value1), 
    convert(int,value2), 
    convert(int,value3),
    convert(int,total) 
from [dbo].#CITY_TABLE
```

Comment: I cleaned up this sample, but @Larnu has it right above. That WITH ROLLUP is a great tip and much cleaner (and he's right about fixing the data typing, too)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do this as:

```
select v.city_street, sum(t.value1) as value1, sum(t.value2) as value2, sum(t.value3) as value3
from #CityTable ct cross apply
     (values (city), (street)
     ) v(city_street)
group by city_street;
```

This assumes that the numbers are really stored as numbers rather than strings.